# Include JS file in .vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have to include pusher.js in my `.vue` file like this:

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/5.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

I can see in the console `ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined`.

How can we include js files like this in .vue files? I cant even execute the js code in `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't include script directly in `.vue` file. Rather, you have to import the file:

```
import Pusher from 'path-to-pusher'
```

Comment: so basically `import Pusher from './PATH/TO/JS/Pusher.js` ?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use .js just `./PATH/TO/JS/Pusher` will work fine.

Comment: Glad to help :)